# how to use jest's .toHaveBeenCalledWith() with a matcher

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have been adding tests to a React project and I have been continually plagued with slight syntax errors when I use the toHaveBeenCalledWith method. I don't actually care if the syntax is exactly correct, I just want to make sure it contains the desired message.

```
it("catches the error if network error occurs", async () => {        
        let errorMessage = "There has been a network error";
        mockAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject(new Error(errorMessage)))
        
        snackbarSetter = jest.fn()
        const service2 = new ReleaseFormService();
        await service2.addReleases(releasesURL, releasesBody, headers, pushNewReleases, toggleLoading, snackbarSetter);

        expect(snackbarSetter).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        expect(snackbarSetter).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['Error :' + errorMessage], "error")
    })
```

This test fails with the message -

```
 Expected: ["Error :There has been a network error"], "error"
 Received: [Error: There has been a network error], "error"
```

This is the third time a unit test has been mostly successful but failing because of a minor difference. So now I am looking for away around using exact syntax but so far my efforts combine the stringContaining method with the HaveBeenCalledWith have been fruitless.

Any suggestions? To be clear, I don't need help with this specific test which I have already refactored to pass but to save time on future tests.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the thrown `Error` object as a `prop` to `snackbarSetter`?

Comment: It's not an array containing a string, that's how an *actual error object* is represented.

Comment: Use a regex to match the message.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only need the message of the error in this case, maybe something like this

```
let error =""

try{
  throw new Error("something")
} catch (e) {
   error = e.message
}

snackbarSetter(error)
```

Then you can assert like this.

```
expect(snackbarSetter).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`Error : ${errorMessage}`, "error")
```